# Dynamic HTML page fro different customers

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net HTML page which contains plain html tables with dynamic data populated. and few paragraphs and images in between the page.

requirement: If i want to give the same page to different customers they may show interest in changing the design of the page

So , how to generate/configure a html page which should be given to both customers and they generate the table columns  with there interest. one may interest in showing 3 columns and other showing 5 columns and css styles may also differ between two customers.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a little more clear please? I am not sure what the problem is. From what your saying it sounds like you need dynamic tables? Is this a problem for mobile or something? I am not the biggest web developer would assume your server could deliver dynamic html based on the customer with a server side programming language like PHP or a script.

Comment: Yes i want to show the same page with different UI for 2 different customers - tables with 2 columns on the page and tables with 3 coulmns on the page also applying different background color of the page and css styles differ.

Comment: Basically we need to create templates in the image server and call those templates for different customers

Comment: Why not use php or something on the serverside, or do it dynamically with JS requesting information either from the server or client?